# How to stop Blogger from adding indentation style in image links?

Tags: html, styles, margin, indentation, blogger

I have a follow-up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607245/how-can-i-remove-unwanted-left-margin-padding-from-post-images). 
I'm running a blog on blogger.com where I publish quite a lot of pictures, and I also have this problem with margin-left 1em and margin-right 1em inserted as inline style for every linked picture, creating an unwanted indentation. I can always remove these manually from every picture, but it would be so much easier if I could stop blogger from inserting these automatically. Does anyone know how?

Example of generated HTML:

```
<a href="(link URL)" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;">
     <img src="(image URL)" />
</a>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<script language='javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[

/**
this script was written by Confluent Forms LLC http://www.confluentforms.com
for the BlogXpertise website http://www.blogxpertise.com
any updates to this script will be posted to BlogXpertise
please leave this message and give credit where credit is due!
**/

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.post-body').find('img').each(function(n, image){
        var image = $(image);
        image.parent().css('margin-left',0).css('margin-right',0).css('margin-top',0).css('margin-bottom',0);
    });
});
//]]></script>
```

Paste this code right in the beginning of the `<head>` tag in your template

Answer (score 0):

We can't change the markup that Blogger adds by default to the anchor tags of images but we can override these by using CSS

Add the following CSS in your blog (To add CSS , go to Blogger Dashboard > your blog > Template > Customise > Advanced > Add CSS )

```
.separator a {
margin-left: 0 !important;
margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: @JaneHelen I checked the site www.veganmisjonen.com & saw that the above CSS was present but not working.The reason why it wasn't working is because the CSS above has missing closing brackets which cause Browser to not interpret the CSS after it.Also there are around 3000 lines of CSS added via Add CSS option,of which 2000-2500 are repeated.Lastly to make this work you can enclose it in a <style> tag & add it just below <head> tag.The above Answer does the same thing as this CSS(you would see same properties in it)but adds around 80+ KB to load the jQuery library which slows down loading speed